# Oracle SQL - query from one table with two conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to select data from a table by two conditions

I have four tables

**Tran**

| tranid | payed |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | yes |
| 456 | yes |
| 789 | no |

**Info**

| tranid | contractname | amount | currency | accountid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | finance | 10 | EUR | 12345 |
| 123 | card | 8 | USD | 54321 |
| 456 | finance | 20 | EUR | 67890 |
| 456 | card | 16 | USD | 09876 |
| 789 | finance | 30 | EUR | 13579 |
| 789 | card | 24 | USD | 97531 |

**Account**

| accountid | currencyid |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 | 124 |
| 54321 | 978 |
| 67890 | 124 |
| 09876 | 840 |
| 13579 | 124 |
| 97531 | 826 |

**Currency**

| currencyid | currencyname |
| --- | --- |
| 978 | EUR |
| 840 | USD |
| 826 | GBP |
| 124 | CAD |

I need to extract: **tran id** where payed = yes, **amount** where contract name = finance and **account currency name** where contact name = card

I have tried to make join with multiple select, but I always have error: **ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row**

```
select t.tranid,
   (select i.amount
    from tranid t
    inner join info i on t.tranid = i.tranid
    and t.payed = 'yes'
    and i.contractname = 'finance') as "Amount",
c.currencyname as "Account currency"
from tran t
inner join info i on t.tranid = i.tranid
inner join account a on i.accountid = a.accountid
inner join currency c on a.currencyid= c.currencyid
and t.payed = 'yes'
and i.contractname = 'card'
```

**Result must be:**

| tranid | Amount | Account currency |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 10 | EUR |
| 456 | 20 | USD |

Comment: In your data do you have finance twice on a transID? `SELECT contractName, tranID FROM info WHERE contractName = 'Finance' GROUP BY TranID Having count(*) > 1`  Assuming TranID on Tran is a Unique Index/PK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that your subquery is not *correlated* with your main query - it doesn't reference any of the outer query tables. If you run it by itself, you'll notice that it returns 2 rows.

```
select i.amount
from tranid t
inner join info i on t.tranid = i.tranid
and t.payed = 'yes'
and i.contractname = 'finance'
```

Also, when you reference the same table multiple times in a query, it's good practice to use different aliases for each one, so you can tell them apart.

Here's a relatively small change that should make your query work:

```
select t.tranid,
    (select i2.amount
    from info i2 
    where i2.tranid = i.tranid
    and i2.contractname = 'finance') as "Amount",
c.currencyname as "Account currency"
from tran t
inner join info i on t.tranid = i.tranid
inner join account a on i.accountid = a.accountid
inner join currency c on a.currencyid= c.currencyid
and t.payed = 'yes'
and i.contractname = 'card'
```

Although if it were me, I wouldn't use a subquery at all - I'd just join the `info` table twice.

```
select t.tranid,
    i2.amount as "Amount",
c.currencyname as "Account currency"
from tran t
inner join info i on t.tranid = i.tranid
    and i.contractname = 'card'
inner join info i2 on t.tranid = i2.tranid
    and i2.contractname = 'finance'
inner join account a on i.accountid = a.accountid
inner join currency c on a.currencyid= c.currencyid
and t.payed = 'yes'
```

I don't really understand your `currency` column in the `info` table, it doesn't seem to match up with the `currency` table. But I guess it's not relevant to the question.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand how to solve my problem.

I will provide some changes with twice joining

Here must be select from i.amount not from i2.amount to recieve correct amount

and

inner join account a on i2.accountid = a.accountid must be with i2 not with i as I have to receive correct currency